# How do I properly byte shift a chunk of data?

Tags: c, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have a mmap

```
void *mymap;
mymap = mmap(0, attr.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAPFILE|MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

I opened a file with the HEX content 0x25362364 which is

00100101001101100010001101100100

in binary. Now I want to perform a bit shift:

```
char *str = (char *)mymap;
for(int i=0;i<attr.st_size;i++) {
    str[i] = str[i] >> 4;
}
```

my new file contains the new binary number

00000010000000110000001000000110

but the wished result was to shift everything 4 bits to the right:

00000010010100110110001000110110

how can I accomplish this?
bonus question: if the binary numbers MSB is a 1 how can I have the left side filled up with 0's when shifting right?

Comment: We can start of with why your approach does not work.  A char is 8 bits wide.  When you shift the bits of each char, you throw away the bits that you shifted out from each individual chat; it does not get pushed to the next char in the array.  Now for the solution, that may depend on this question: Is the number of bytes you are working with going to be constant, or is it subject to change?

Comment: Oh, and if you want to make sure that 0s get shifted in when MSB is one, I believe you should be shifting on an unsigned type.

Comment: the number of bytes will be changing. thanks for your reply

Comment: Use Weather Vane's solution (and mark it accepted).  It is the best way to do it for your use case.

Comment: it only works up to 8 bits from what I understood. what if I want to shift a couple hundred bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each byte in the array should be shifted right by 4 bits and ORred with the previous (unsigned) byte shifted left by 4 bits. For example

```
unsigned char *str = (unsigned char *)mymap;
unsigned char prev = 0, next;
for(int i = 0; i < attr.st_size; i++) {
    next  = str[i];
    str[i] = (str[i] >> 4) | (prev << 4);
    prev = next;    
}
```

In the case where you want a right shift of 5 bits, you would shift right by 5 bits and left by 3 bits, sum = 8 (assuming `CHAR_BIT` is 8).

Comment: thanks for your help, this works.
But what do I do if I want to shift more than 8 bits, even up to a couple hundred bits (if it's a larger file)

Comment: Then use an array of `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long` and modify the algorithm accordingly. You might need to beware of endianness, though. This approach won't work for 100 bits, but that should be a different question. Hmmm do you have a 128 bit data type available?

Comment: I suggest to shift a large number of bits, to build another array, with approriate index offsets and shifts.

Comment: If you want to shift by 100 bits you can shift by 12 bytes (using memmove or similar) and then by 4 bits.

Comment: What @immibis said.  You'd essentially have the "rough shift" which moves entire bytes, and then finish with the "fine shift" as WeatherVane already supplied.